# How to json_encode without escaping slashes?

Tags: php, escaping, json

I'm encoding it like so..

```
json_encode($array_list, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

Ex: \n turns into \\n, \r\n turns into \\r\\n

But, it's still escaping the slashes! What's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES is available since PHP5.4 , which version are you running?

Answer (score 25):

I think it is because of `single and double quotes`, see the examples

```
$arr = array("\n\r");
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);  // ["\n\r"]

$arr = array('\n\r');
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);  //["\\n\\r"]
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/LvWMhq

Comment: I'm amazed you got that without him actually posting the `$arr`. Very impressed +1

Answer (score 0):

If it is a concern when doing any MySQL queries then you can use it like this:

`mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($array))`

No need to escape anything in the `$array` itself before this point, just let `mysql_real_escape_string` escape the json_encoded string.